# Line smoothing with Numpy/SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a line which should be smoothened by `scipy.interpolate.splrep` and `scipy.interpolate.splev`.

```
line = ((x1, y1), (x2, y2), ... (xn, yn))
tck = interpolate.splrep(x, y)
```

I need to find more values for my x-coordinate which should be arranged evenly.

```
newx = numpy.XXX(x)
newy = interpolate.splev(newx, tck)
```

e.g. `(1, 2, 4, 3) -> (1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 3.5, 3)`

Is there a "simple" way to achieve this in Numpy/SciPy?

Comment: Why are your x-coordinates not ordered?

Comment: I take it the key problem is when the x series is not monotonically increasing?

Comment: yes you are right, the problem is that the x values are note necessarily increasing. I could also apply linspace to each single pair of coordinates... but I thought there would be sth. "simple".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import scipy.interpolate as interp
z = arange(0,4)
x = np.array([1,2,4,3])
f = interp.interp1d(z, x)
newx = f(np.linspace(z[0],z[-1],7))
```

which should give you

```
In [40]: print z
[0 1 2 3]

In [41]: print x
[1 2 4 3]

In [42]: print newx
[ 1.   1.5  2.   3.   4.   3.5  3. ]
```

which will just linearly interpolate between abscissa points in the order they are defined in the array. Is that what you were thinking of?